# How to fetch the css class block in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Actually I would like to fetch the CSS class block

HTML Code:

```
<a id="fld_2418083_6_opt1730754" data-label="F°" data-field="fld_2418083" data-active="btn-primary" data-default="btn-default" class="btn btn-primary" data-value="0" aria-labelledby="fld_2418083Label" title="Choose OptionF°">F°</a>
```

CSS Code:

```html
.btn-primary{
   background-color: #438bca;
}
```

I have tried this piece of code for fetching the CSS block in python with selenium but I got an error of

```py
cls_name = element.get_attribute("class")
bg_color = cls_name.value_of_css_property("background-color")
print(f'{ bg_color = }')
```

Expecting the output is

> background-color: #438bca`aliceblue`

Answer (score 1):

You did not include the way you retrieve the element and what's the error you encountered. My guess here is you are using the class name which is very general and could have multiple web elements sharing the same class.

To get that specific element, you can use its ID, like below :

```py
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'fld_2418083_6_opt1730754')
bg_color = element.value_of_css_property("background-color")
print(f'{ bg_color = }')
```

With the output of following :

```
bg_color = 'rgba(67, 139, 202, 1)'
```

You can convert it to hex if you like by following :

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.color import Color

hex = Color.from_string(bg_color).hex
print(f'{ hex = }')
```

With the output of following:

```
hex = '#438bca'
```